# JavaScript Array is correct outside loop but undefined inside loop

Tags: javascript

```
function deleteList () {
    var toDoList;
    toDoList = document.getElementById("todo");
    var listArray = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    console.log(listArray);
    /* returns correctly: [li#first.kitchen, li#second.kitchen,
    li#third.kitchen, li#fourth, first: li#first.kitchen, etc... */

    for (var i = 0; i < listArray.length; i++); {
        var listItemHolder = listArray[i];
        console.log(listItemHolder);
        /* Returns undefined */
        toDoList.removeChild(listItemHolder); 
    } 
}
```

I am just making a simple to do list that allows the user to delete all items when they press the "delete button" executing this function.

What I have tried:

- removing the listItemHolder and using just .removeChild(listArray[i]).
- changing the cycles of the for loop to i<4

Any explanation of what is going on would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: have you logged listArray ?

Comment: Provide complete code. Better if you make a fiddle.

Comment: Welcome to SO Robert. _Any explanation of what is going on would be greatly appreciated!_ Actually, you should tell us what's going on and we'll tell you why. ;) We don't know what you're inputting, what you're seeing nor what you're expecting, since you haven't told us. Remember, we can't see your screen or HDD contents. :)

Comment: [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) is a *live* list, so it's not a good idea to change it while you are trying to iterate it. Copy it into a static array.

Answer (score 2):

It's the `;` after the closing parenthesis of the for loop.

Delete it

```
for (var i = 0; i < listArray.length; i++) {
```

What happened?
You have an empty for loop body with this `;`
After the loop `i` has the value of `listArray.length` and `listArray[listArray.length]` is undefinend

You also have to go through the loop backwards.
So instead you should use

```
for (var i = listArray.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

else you will only delete every second item in the list.
How that?
Look here
first you have this list

```
0: todo 1
1: todo 2
2: todo 3
3: todo 4
```

When you have deleted the first one, you have this

```
0: todo 2
1: todo 3
2: todo 4
```

And your counting variable i has the value 1. Next to be deleted is todo 3

```
0: todo 2
1: todo 4
```

This is the end